# Is it necessary to release bitmap local variable?

Tags: c#, bitmap, dispose

I have below method that is called. Within it I create a Bitmap local variable and then it is passed as an argument to an instance of a custom class. My doubt is: Do I have to dispose bitmap object?

```
    public void AddSnapshot(int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
            MyClass mc = new MyClass(bmp);              
        } 
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (bmp != null) bmp.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reagrding to MSDN, not only in this case of an exception you should dispose it.

> "Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the
>   Image. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until
>   the garbage collector calls the Image object's Finalize method."

As you do via:

```
bitmap.Dispose();
```

Regarding to: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2

Bitmap is derived from Image, and MSDN says you should call `Dispose()` on Images.

Comment: Ok, but my doubt is: do i have to dispose it if no exception is raised?

Comment: In general MSDN says: Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Image. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Image object's Finalize method.

Comment: So according to MSDN, I have to put bmp.Dispose() as well just after  MyClass mc = new MyClass(bmp).